# Strange output in a while loop(C language)

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, output

i just started learning C and don't understand why does the code segment below output 30. And why it doesn't output a number each iteration.

```
int k=3, f=3;
while (k<10)
     K++;
     f*=k;
printf("%d", f);
```

And when added curly braces it outputs 1814400, which in my opinion is the correct output

```
int k=3, f=3;
while (k<10){
     K++;
     f*=k;
}
printf("%d", f);
```

Could you explain why outputs are different?

Comment: Exactly what to you think the braces is doing?

Comment: Do you happen to be a python coder?

Answer (score 0):

In the first snippet, this code

```
while (k<10)
    K++;
```

Increases `k` to `10`. The next statement, `f*=k;`, is **not** part of the loop. So it gets executed after the loop, setting `f` to `30`.

In your second snippet, both the `K++;` and `f*=k;` are part of the loop body, so both of them get executed each run through the loop.

It's more clear if you indent it properly:

```
int main()
{
    int k = 3, f = 3;
    while (k < 10)
        k++;
    f *= k;
    printf("%d", f);
}
```

Now it is clear that `f *= k;` isn't part of the loop in the first snippet.

For clarification, [here's](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/while) a documentation that explains the syntax:

> while ( expression ) statement

Only the statement following the `while()` is part of the loop. With the braces `{}` you get a compound statement to be the loop's body.

---

Also note that `k` is not the same as `K` and it wouldn't compile this way, but I guess this is some auto-formatting that happened when you pasted the code.

Comment: thanks for the answer, feel stupid that didn't understand what was so simple